# Rust expected enum `syn::UseTree`, found struct `syn::Path`

Tags: rust, destructuring

I am new to Rust and trying to figure out how to get into a workflow of discovering the structure of this AST returned by [syn](https://github.com/dtolnay/syn).

```
[package]
name = "rust-ast"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
syn = { version = "1.0.89", features = ["full", "printing", "visit", "extra-traits"] }
```

That is the Cargo.toml, and here is the main file:

```
use syn;

use std::env;
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::Read;
use std::process;

fn main() {
  let mut args = env::args();
  let _ = args.next(); // executable name

  let filename = match (args.next(), args.next()) {
    (Some(filename), None) => filename,
    _ => {
      eprintln!("Usage: dump-syntax path/to/filename.rs");
      process::exit(1);
    }
  };

  let mut file = File::open(&filename).expect("Unable to open file");

  let mut src = String::new();
  file.read_to_string(&mut src).expect("Unable to read file");

  let syntax = syn::parse_file(&src).expect("Unable to parse file");

  let mut str = String::from("");

  for item in syntax.items {
    match item {
      syn::Item::Use(x) => {
        match x.tree {
          syn::path::Path { .. } => {
            println!("{:#?}", x);
          },

        }
        str.push_str("load");
      },
      _ => println!("Skip")
    }
  }
  // let iterator = syntax.iter();
  // for val in iterator {
  //   println!("Got: {:#?}", val);
  // }
}
```

[image]

I was able to earlier print out the `x`, which showed:

[image]

However, I am getting this error now:

```
this expression has type `syn::UseTree`
expected enum `syn::UseTree`, found struct `syn::Path`
```

First of all, how do I discover the API in VSCode? I have enabled the rust plugin so I can click through *some* definitions, but I look at that terminal output of the AST "types", and then I try to backward figure out what the type is in VSCode. Usually I resort to looking it up on the [docs page](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html?search=UsePath), but any tips on how to figure out what the API should be would help teach me to fish. But for this particular question, what am I doing wrong? I am simply trying to destructure the AST as much as possible down to the leaves, to get more familiar with Rust (I am just beginning).

Comment: You want to match on `syn::UseTree::Path { .. }` here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But for this particular question, what am I doing wrong?

`x.tree` is of type [`UseTree`](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/enum.UseTree.html) which is an enum:

```
pub enum UseTree {
    Path(UsePath),
    Name(UseName),
    ... other variants snipped ...
}
```

Therefore you need to match on the `Path` variant of `UseTree`:

```
match x.tree {
    UseTree::Path { .. } => { ... },
    _ => todo!(),
}
```

> First of all, how do I discover the API in VSCode?

I don't use VS code but I find clicking through works well for Rust and the stdlib and less well for macro heavy libraries such as `syn`.  Fortunately the [documentation](https://docs.rs/syn/latest/syn/) for `syn` is really good.

> am simply trying to destructure the AST as much as possible down to the leaves, to get more familiar with Rust (I am just beginning).

`syn` can be quite complex and so I wouldn't advise this as an approach to learning the language.